# How do I reduce the size of an entire LaTeX table?

Tags: latex

I have a table that I want to appear a little smaller to save some space. What environment can I put it in to shrink the whole table by a fraction ?

Comment: This is off-topic on stackoverflow; LaTeX questions should go on http://tex.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @Brooks. Not sure. Why is SO not porting all the tex questions to tex.SE ?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70466/can-so-questions-on-tex-be-migrated-to-tex-sx.  My take is that there's no auto-port for all TeX questions because a few of them _are_ programming, but that most of them really belong on the TeX.stackexchange site.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Use `\resizebox`:

```latex
\resizebox{3cm}{!}{
  \begin{something}
    something
  \end{something}
  }
```

The `!` tells LaTeX to keep the aspect ratio.  You can also scale the y direction differently by giving a value there.

Comment: this doesn't work with long tables :/

Comment: Yes, because long tables are not a single box but multiple boxes.  If you scale something there, you will probably also want to make page breaks at different points, so this needs to be built into the table, not around it.  You can probably get somewhere by adjusting font size and paddings of the contents.

Comment: thank you for explaining. Indeed I solved it by reducing the font size (new to latex here!)

Comment: This just gives me ```Undefined control sequence.
l.164 \resizebox
                {3cm}{!}{
? ```, so seems to not work anymore? or does it need some plugin?

Comment: Ah, sorry, it seems that it's in graphicx, so you need \usepackage{graphicx}.

Answer (score 11):

Scaling elements that contain text is really not a good idea (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425453/why-not-scale-elements-that-contain-text for more information) therefore here are two other approaches how to reduce the size of a table:

- reducing the inter column space with `\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-1pt}`
- manually selecting a smaller font size, e.g. with font commands like `\small` or for more fine control `\fontsize{9.5pt}{10.25pt}\selectfont`

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

Reducing the inter column spacing a bit:
\begin{table}[htbp]
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-1pt}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline
some text some text & some text some text & some text some text some text\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2]

Smaller font size:
\begin{table}[htbp]
\small
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline
some text some som text & some text some text & some text some text some text\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: changing the font size seems to be the best option for long tables

Answer (score -1):

```
\begin{table}[tch]
\caption{foo}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline 
\footnotesize{
foo&foo&foo\\
foo&doo&fofo\\
}\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{foo}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Te syntax is a bit off. `\fotnotesize` is a switch which does not take an argument. Therefore it should be `\footnotesize ...` instead of `\footnotesize{...}`

Answer (score -1):

This is an example:

```
\begin{table}[h!] 
\resizebox{6cm}{!} 
{ 
% here is the table content.
}
%\caption{Versiones a comparar.} 
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please improve your answer by adding at least a few words to help explain it.

Comment: Please have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425453/why-not-scale-elements-that-contain-text Scaling fonts is really not a good idea

Comment: This is an example:

\begin{table}[h!] 
\resizebox{6cm}{!} 
{ 
\begin{tabular}{l} \hline \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Clase}} \\ \hline
Contenido adiposo (Grasa) \\ 
\end{tabular}
}
%\caption{Versiones a comparar.} 
\end{table}

Comment: I mean about resize the size in a table in latex. I use this code for example in Beamer and it's success

Comment: Sorry for the code unindented but, I haven't understood how to put very well my answers in stack overflow in order to put latex code. But the code that I write in my comments is true. I used it in my presentation on latex.

Comment: \resizebox is the command to add between tabular tag in order to resize the table. It have three parameters \resize{}{}{} in the example I wrote \resize{6cm}{!}{ <<table content>>} in this case 6cm is six centimeter the size of the table content, you can change this number.

Comment: If you need information about how to create tables on latex automatically please use the web site https://www.tablesgenerator.com and resize the table using \resizebox command put it between \beging{table} and \beging{tabular}. For example: \beging{table} \resizebox{6cm}{!}{ \beging{tabular} <<content table>> \end{table}  }%close the resize box \end{tabular}